# Can not map table in NHibernate. GenericADOException

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate

I am new at mapping tables with NHibernate andIi have a weird problem. I am getting exception called GenericADOException. I says it could not load entity and gives me this query

```
[SQL: SELECT user0_.id_user as id1_2_0_, user0_.username as username2_0_, user0_.password as password2_0_, user0_.name as name2_0_, user0_.surname as surname2_0_ 
      FROM dbo.User user0_ 
      WHERE user0_.id_user=?]
```

But it seems alright, table name is exactly same and all columns are correct. If I try to execute query in management studio it throws

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'User'.

I am not able to figure this out. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User is a reserved for in SqlServer.  you need to configure NHibernate to AutoQuote tables and columns.

this is the property that needs to be set

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.keywords">auto-quote</property>
```

This can also be achieved using Mapping By Code:

```
        Configure.DataBaseIntegration(db =>
                                      {
                                          db.Dialect<MsSql2008Dialect>();
                                          db.Driver<SqlClientDriver>();
                                          db.KeywordsAutoImport = Hbm2DDLKeyWords.AutoQuote;
                                          db.IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;
                                          db.ConnectionString = _connectionString;
                                          db.BatchSize = 20;
                                          db.Timeout = 10;
                                          db.HqlToSqlSubstitutions = "true 1, false 0, yes 'Y', no 'N'";
                                      });
```